# Is There A Way To Disable thumbnails on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, thumbnails

Is there a way to disable thumbnails from being made (captured) on Ubuntu 12.04? I'm referring in:

~/home/xxxx/.thumbnails

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could simlink the .thumbnails folder to /dev/null like this:

```
ln -s /home/username/.thumbnails /dev/null
```

You could also setup a cron job that cleans the folder out at regular intervals. You could create a script that says:

```
rm -rf /home/username/.thumbnails/*
```

Save that as something like clearThumbCache.sh in your home folder. Make it executable with:

```
chmod +x clearThumbCache.sh
```

Then in a terminal do:

```
cron -e
```

And enter:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/username/clearThumbCache.sh
```

That will set the script to run every 5 minutes.

You could also try, in Nautilus, go to Edit -> Preferences -> Preview and set "Show Thumbnails" to "Never" and see if that would prevent anything from appearing in that folder.

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm glad I could help.